# How to determine the eigenvectors of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have some problems to determine the eigenvectors of a given matrix:

The matrix is:

$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right)
$$

I calculated the eigenvalues first and got $$ \lambda_1  = 1, \lambda_2 = 2, \lambda_3 = 1$$
There was no problem for me so far. But I do not know how to determine the eigenvectors. The formula I have to use is
$$ (A-\lambda_i E)u=0, \lambda_i = \{1,2,3\}, u\ is\ eigenvector$$
When I determined the eigenvector with $ \lambda_2=2$ there was not a problem. I got the result that $x_3 = variable$ and $x_2 = x_3$, so:
$$ 
EV_2= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
\beta \\
\beta
\end{array} \right) \ \beta\ is\ variable,\ so\ EV = span\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \\
1
\end{array} \right)\}
$$

But when I used $ \lambda_1 = \lambda_3 = 1 $, I  had to calculate:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right) * 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{array} \right)
=0
$$

what in my opinion means that $x_3 = 0 $ and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are variable, but not necessarily the same as in the case above, so $ EV_{1,3} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha \\
\beta \\
0
\end{array} \right) $

What does that mean for my solution? is it
$$
EV_{1,3} = span\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)\}
$$

What exactly is now my solution in this case for the eigenvectors $ \lambda_1, \lambda_3 $? In university we just had one variable value in the matrix so I don't know how to handle two of them being different.

Comment: I deleted my post because I am in error. Sorry, and disregard my comments. However. The Wolf gives 3 eigenvectors https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%28%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D+%2C%5B0%2C+1%2C1%5D+%2C%5B0%2C0%2C2%5D%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every linear combination of $EV_{1}=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$ and $EV_3=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$ is a eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

$EV_{1,3} = span\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)\}$
is the same as $EV_{1,3} = span\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right),
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I think my main problem is that I don't see why $(1,1,0)^T$ is not really necessary. Could you explain it to my why it is the same with or without $(1,1,0)^T$ ?

Comment: @Drudge because $\pmatrix{1\\1\\0}$ lies in the vector space that is spanned by the other two...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not know about this context here. But I think I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update: I have undeleted my answer because I think it is fixed now.

You got $$ V_{\lambda_2} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right) $$

correct but then copied it down wrongly.(I think..)

Then you correctly wrote down the case $\lambda_1$. From

$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc } 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $$

you should easily conclude (I think you did) that $ z = 0 $ ,  x and y can be anything leading to

$$ V_{\lambda_{1 \ or \ 3}} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc } 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) $$

Now , since the dimension of the nullspace is 2 we can decompose this into 2 seperate eigenvectors corresponding to the repeated eigenvalue of 1

$$ V_{ \lambda_1} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc } 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) \ \ , \ \  V_{ \lambda_2 } = \left(\begin{array}{ccc } 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right) \ \ , \ \  V_{ \lambda_3} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc } 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) $$

You can check all three are independent and satisfy

$$AV_i = \lambda_iV_i$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I didn't used $ V_{\lambda_2} $ anymore after I determined it. Where exactly did I copy it down wrongly?

I also thought that $ (1,1,0)^T $ was a correct solution but my excecise instructor striked my solution and wrote $$ \{[(1,0,0)^T, (0,1,0)^T]\} $$ beneath it. That was my main intention to ask the question. But when I read the first answer, it seems that he has made a mistake.

Comment: I didn't see you present $(0,1,1)^T$ as an eigenvector so I thought you copied it down as a typo $(1,1,0)$

Comment: I kind of thought that, no problem. But thank you anyway! Edit: Oh sorry, I see your edit only now. Thank you for explaining the case with $ (1,1,0)^T $!

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes when we get a repeated eigenvalue we can't get enough vectors , it all depends on the dimension of the nullspace. In other words , if you have $n$ eigenvalues ALL DISTINCT then you get $n$ independent eigenvectors , but let's say we have an eigenvalue of $k$ that repeats 3 times , then that eigenvalue is gauranteed to produce 1 eigenvector , you may get 2 or 3 but not more than 3 ( corresponding to that k) and depending on the dimension of the nullspace.